# Fitting two functions simultaniously with scipy's curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, simultaneous

Say I have defined two real-valued functions of the independent variable `x` and some parameters in the following form:

- `f(x, parameters)`
- `g(x, parameters)`

(Alternatively: one function which returns a 2-tuple of real numbers, `(f(x),g(x))`).

I would now like to use scipy's `curve_fit` to fit both curves **simultaneously** to two data arrays, `fdata` and `gdata`, with their associated errors: `fdata-err`, `gdata-err` (i.e. finding the best parameters that fit the data). Is this possible?

I know I could define a new function which is the sum of the differences between both functions and their respective measurements, but the python's minimizing functions don't seem to yield or account for errors, which is very important for my purpose.

Comment: You can (or have to) handle the errors yourself in the to-be-minimized function. You can take a look at the implementation to see how that's done in `curve_fit`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L576

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured this is a rather common thing to do, so I was hoping there's a built-in option. I'll do as you suggest (unless others are aware of an alternative solution!)

Comment: Why not using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` with the sum of squared errors for *f* and for *g*: `sum((fdata - f(xdata))**2/fdata-err**2)+sum((gdata - g(xdata))**2/gdata-err**2)`?

Comment: Yeah, I'll define this sum myself and minimize it. I just didn't feel like working on the output errors (the uncertainties) myself... I liked the fact that curve_fit does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do something similar and found an alternative without defining a custom least square function.

One way would be to define another function h(x, parameters) which is just a concatenation of f() and g().

```
import numpy as np
def h(x, params):
  fr = f(x, params)
  gr = g(x, params)

  hr = np.hstack(fr, gr)

  return hr
```

Similarly, you will have to concatenate the ydata for both f() and g().

```
fdata = [..] ## value of ydata of f
gdata = [..] ## value of ydata of g

hdata = np.hstack(fdata, gdata)
```

In the same way xdata also has to be repeated.

```
xdata_new = np.hstack(xdata, xdata)
```

Now you are ready to call `curve_fit()`.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimization

popt, pcov = optimization.curve_fit(f=h, xdata=xdata_new, ydata=ydata)

print(popt)
```

NB: You may have to change a few things based on how you have defined f() and g(). But the basic structure should hold.